# Add attribute to XML in ASP.NET webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET

I managed to put MS SQL Server database into xml document, but what I'm trying to do now is, to add an attribute to the XML, which will be an `id` from the database.

something like:

```
<Products>
    <product id=1>
        <name>Some name</name> 
    </product>
    <product id=2>
        <name>Some other</name> 
    </product>
    <product id=3>
        <name>Some other name</name> 
    </product>
</Products>
```

This is what I have so far:
`products.asmx.cs`:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument productsAll()
{
    string conString = "Data Source=my_db.com;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString);

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Products";

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdptr = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dataAdptr.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
    DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet("Products");
    dataAdptr.Fill(dsProducts, "product");

    XmlDocument xmlDom = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDom.LoadXml(dsProducts.GetXml());
    return xmlDom;
}
```

Comment: `.asmx` web services are dead - check out either WCF or the new ASP.NET WebAPI for REST services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create the XML in SQL Server and just read out the resulting XML.

Try something like this:

```
public XmlDocument productsAll()
{
    // define connection string
    string conString = "Data Source=my_db.com;Integrated Security=True";

    // define SQL query to use 
    string query = "SELECT ID AS '@ID', Name FROM dbo.Products FOR XML PATH('Product'), ROOT('Products')";

    // set up connection and command objects
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
    {
       // open connection
       sqlConn.Open();

       // execute query, read out the XML from the T-SQL query
       string xmlContents = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

       // close connection
       sqlConn.Close();

       // parse XML received from SQL Server into a XmlDocument and return
       XmlDocument xmlDom = new XmlDocument();
       xmlDom.LoadXml(xmlContents);

       return xmlDom;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error `SQLException was unhandled...` on `string xmlContents`

Comment: @knowbody: your connection string is incomplete - you have a `Data Source` (a server name), but no database name..... try something like:  `string conString = "server=my_db.com;database=XXXXXXXXX;Integrated Security=True;` and replace the XXXXXX with whatever your actual database name is

Comment: it's all good now. ^ that, plus you could do `sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar as string` in case you get `null` but all works fine. super old school. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering from a linux machine so don't have SQL Server handy right now. Please check T-SQL help for the SELECT FOR XML. You can control the structure of the resulting XML.